# How to write promise.all for this?

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs

The code returns an array with all the records from medicine database where the id and email matches.I am trying to send the array to the react interface using the JSON but the data received is an empty array because res.json is executed before forloop. I think because it is asynchronous, how do I resolve this?

`//nodejs`

```
app.get("/getinventory", (req, res) => {

    db.query(getinventorysql,[EmailID],(err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            var string=JSON.stringify(result);
            var json =  JSON.parse(string);
            console.log(json[0])
            console.log("Result Length",result.length)

            for(let i=0; i<result.length;++i)
            {
                output.push(AsyncFunc(i,json))
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(output))
            //console.log("getBrandandManufacturersql",output)
            res.json(output)
        }
        
    });
});
```

`//reactjs` This fetches the data and stores it in an array to be used in a dropdown

```
const [inventoryList, setinventoryList] = useState([])
 
useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/getinventory').then((response) => {
        setinventoryList(response.data);
             
        console.log("Update",response)
    });
},[]);
```

`//The code i attempted (didnt work)` inside app.get i used Promise but still res.json is executed before forloop

```
let getinventorysql = `SELECT * FROM inventory where EmailID=?`;
let getinventorysql2 = `SELECT * FROM medicinedatabase where idMedicineDatabase=?`;
var idMedicineDatabase;
var EmailID="";
var output =[];
var j=0;
  app.get("/getinventory", (req, res) => {
    var output = new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
        setTimeout(() => {
            db.query(getinventorysql,[EmailID],(err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    var string=JSON.stringify(result);
                    var json =  JSON.parse(string);
                    console.log("Result Length",result.length)
                    for(let i=0; i<result.length;i++)
                    {
                        console.log("i",i)
    
                        idMedicineDatabase=json[i].idMedicineDatabase
                        EmailID=json[i].EmailID
                        db.query(getinventorysql2,[idMedicineDatabase],(err, result1) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            } else {
                              output.push(result1)
                              console.log("loop",result1)
                              console.log("loop")
                              j++
                            }
                    
                        });
                    }
                    if(j>0)
                    {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(output))
                        //console.log("getBrandandManufacturersql",output)
                        resolve(output)
                    }
                    
                }
          }, 100);
    })
    });
    Promise.all([output]).then(values => {
        console.log("DataSent");
        console.log(output)
        res.json(output)
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you don't need the loop at all. You can use a `IN` operator to get all medicinedatabases in a single query like so:

```
let getinventorysql2 = `SELECT * FROM medicinedatabase where idMedicineDatabase IN (${result.map(r => r.idMedicineDatabase).join(',')})`;
```

The above code should produce a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM medicinedatabase where idMedicineDatabase IN (id1,id2,id3)
```

So the whole code might look like this (NOT TESTED):

```
app.get("/getinventory", (req, res) => {

    db.query(getinventorysql,[EmailID],(err, result) => {

        let getinventorysql2 = `SELECT * FROM medicinedatabase where idMedicineDatabase IN (${result.map(r => r.idMedicineDatabase).join(',')})`;
        
        db.query(getinventorysql2, (err, result2) => {

            res.json(resul2)

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @AbhitayShinde You're welcome, feel free to accept my answer ;)